# Can you provide a short circuit protection circuit to use with a regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, short-circuit

I recently shorted my AMS1117 voltage regulator while probing on a DSO. It blew off. I am wondering, is there a short circuit protection circuit which I can use with any configuration voltage regulator.

Answer (score 1):

A fuse and or a resettable PPTC (Poly Fuse) are the two simplest ways to provide short circuit protection. A single component in the high or low end of a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

There are load switches that monitor the current flow. If the current exceeds a maximum for example due to a short the current get limited. If this situation persists, the load monitor will shut down and preventing any further harm.

One example of such a chip is the FPF2123 from Fairchild which I like a lot.

On the other hand the AMS1117 that you've used has internal short circuit protection, so even if you short the output the AMS1117 should be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure about AMS1117 short circuit protection. I got a few from eBay, but at least 5V version fails badly by shorting Vin to Vout (burning the rest of circuit if there is no other protections) if powered by 12V/2A regulated power supply. I'm not sure if there is just many low quality fakes around, or datasheet is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to protect a power supply from over-current.  Simple ones are a single-use fuse or a "polyfuse".  There are also various resettable circuit breakers.  A more complicated way is to have a electronic circuit watch the voltage across a small current sense resistor, and switch off a series FET when it gets too high.  That is often called a "electronic fuse".

However, it seems you are overreacting.  You screwed up and blew up a part.  It happens.  Get over it.

You have to ask yourself how likely this kind of failure is in the field and what the consequences are.  If it is unlikely and the consequences not severe (device may stop working, but nobody is going to get shocked, won't catch fire, not running critical systems, etc), then probably the best thing to do is nothing.  All the methods to deal with this failure cost money, board space, possibly power, and may also degrade performance.  Adding protection isn't free, so you always have to look at both sides of the issue and make a tradeoff.  There is no place for knee-jerking in engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Those parts, even from amazon, are about $0.20 each.

It is likely that any protection on-board mechanism able to pass enough current to let the AMS1117 operate close to its typical rating, *and* fast enough to protect from a dead short will be *many* times more expensive.

I have worked with people who have blown voltage regulators protected by polyfuses. A polyfuse is better than nothing, but they can be 'beaten'.

IMHO The issue is the way the circuit was probed, and not the protection circuit. If you are intending to do lots of electronics, you'll come across lots of systems which have no protection, so it may be worth adopting a couple of different tactics.

An alternative, effective, but much more expensive solution is to use a proper Bench Power Supply Unit (PSU) which has a user-controlled current limit. Then you can power your circuit and the PSU will restrict the current to a level set by you. A PSU is often used in colleges to teach electronic engineering, and it works (providing the student sets the current limit) to reduce the amount of 'electronic carnage' created in the labs.

Ultimately, the long term solution may be to learn a safer methodology to probing a circuit to minimise the likelihood of damaging the circuit under test. If you are panning a long term career in electronics, that may be a valuable skill.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sufficient voltage margin you could put an LM317 in constant-current mode on top of (= before) your regulator. But as Olin remarked: nothing is free, you'd have to ask yourself whether this is worth the trouble.